# Which PHP string functions NEED to be replaced with mb_* to be UTF-8 safe?

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring

I'm happy to use all the multibyte string functions in my app, but when using external libraries it would a pain to find and replace them all.

Given I can [control](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) external input so that only UTF-8 data will be present, issues that arise from comparing two different encoding types won't be a problem (i.e. `str_replace` is fine as is).

So which string functions do I **need** to replace with the `mb_*` equivalent?

So far I'm sure I need to replace

- strpos()
- strlen()
- substr()

Are there any others?

Alternatively, is using [overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) a viable option, or is this likely to cause issues?

Comment: Go to http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php, Ctrl + F and search for `mb_s`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Is there any logic behind that?